# How do I create or find a wallpaper that fits in my website?

Tags: html, wallpaper

How can I create a wallpaper that fits correctly on to my website???

Would I have to create specific dimensions for the image to fit in the website???

Or where can I find website wallpapers that have correct dimensions to fit the screen???

Comment: By using a css file you can stretch the image or fill the background with the said image. Take a look at here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: You may find this tutorial useful: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go to paint (or other image editing software) to change the size of it. Save it, and then run it. But that might not always work and may ruin the quality of the image.

I know this is a huge issue sometimes when you're finding one online. You can also use the css background-size property.

For more information
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp